# pHp Issue: "Waiting for localhost": Maybe infinite loop issue?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am currently working on an elo based matchmaking system. Basically, I have a database where there are a bunch of users, each having their respective ratings.

Brief explanation of code, it chooses one user at random, and chooses another user if the second user is within +-100 difference-elo of the first user (so grandmasters don't play with bronze players). If there is no one within 100 elo, the difference-elo increments by 50 and checks again.

Problem: I created a test user that is 100 elo more than the other users to test the matchmaking system. The program works except for when the first selected player is my test user. The page never loads and it is stuck on "Waiting for localhost". I assumed this meant one of my while loops was going on infinitely, but after spending sometime editing them and trying to figure out why they might be going on infinitely, the error still persists.

```
<?php


include('mysql.php');
include('functions.php');



$result2 = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY score DESC");
function executeQuery($query2){
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password","database");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
    return $result2;
}

// Get random
$query="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
$result = @mysqli_query($connection, $query);

//Put random in images array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $images[] = (object) $row;
}
//Get elo of random
$elo1 = $images[0]->score;


--------------------------
//Point of Interest Below
--------------------------


//Sort database by DESC. Then go through entire database. If current row's elo is with +- difference (which right now is 100) of elo1's rating, ($elo1-100 < x < $elo1+100), then put into new array with all matchups.
//Get length of array, if length is 0 (meaning no match ups were found), increase difference by 50 and try again. 
$potentialMatchup = [];
$diff = 100;
$arrayLength = count($potentialMatchup);
while ($arrayLength == 0){
    $diff += 50;
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)){
        if(($row2->score > $elo1-$diff) && ($row2->score < $elo1+$diff)){
            $potentialMatchup[] = (object) $row2;
        }
    }
    $arrayLength = count($potentialMatchup);
}


-------------------------------


//Get random index between 0 and length of array.
$randomNumber = rand(0, $arrayLength-1);
//Put match up into images array
$images[1] = (object) $potentialMatchup[$randomNumber];


//Get names of images
$nameLeft = $images[0]->filename;
$nameRight = $images[1]->filename;

//If same person, pick another random
while($nameLeft == $nameRight){
    $randomNumber = rand(0, $arrayLength-1);
    $images[1] = (object) $potentialMatchup[$randomNumber];
    $nameRight = $images[1]->filename;
 }

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($connection);
$leftName = str_replace("_", " ", $images[0]->filename);
$rightName = str_replace("_", " ", $images[1]->filename);


?>
```

Comment: Did you check php error logs?

Comment: In `while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)){` you read all the rows of `$result2`, so when you try `while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)){` there is nothing left to read.

Comment: Hey Nigel, your comment is 100% correct. I have edited the code above which removes the first while loop within the Point of Interest area altogether. It seems like the issue is that I cannot run that inner while loop, what you suggested, more than once. I'm unsure how to fix this. What do you suggest?

Comment: What happens with `while($nameLeft == $nameRight){` if there's only one potential matchup?

Comment: MatsLindh, that while loop is to check if the second user chosen is the same person as the first. If it is, I have that while loop choose a different person.